# Show marker view by default in MpChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using **MpChart's** **LineChart** for showing my graphs. I have added multiple data set lines. Everything is working fine. But i want the **MarkerView** should be set to some point in the middle and should be visible by default. Right now marker view is visible only when I touch it. Is there any method to achieve this ?

Initial graph

[image: Initial graph]
Markerview shown after graph is touched

[image: MarkerView]

Answer (score 2):

Is it help?

```
for (IDataSet set : mChart.getData().getDataSets())
     set.setDrawValues(true);

mChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the IOS version of this lib.But as the documentation says they almost identical, so i hope my answer is correctly "translated".
What i did was get a point where your default marker will always be shown.

Default point were the marker should be locked, define own your point based on HighestVisibleX or something else.

Then on first render i highlight this point:

```
Highlight myFirstRenderedHighlight = new Highlight(myLockedMarkerPoint.x, 0); 
someChart.highlightValues(new Highlight[] { myFirstRenderedHighlight });
```

So if u always want to show this point even when dragging along x-axis, then u need to redraw the highlight. This can be done by listening on chartTranslation This can be done by implementing the interface *OnChartGestureListener. onChartTranslate()* , example:

```
// same logic as picking first point with HighestVisibleX or something
Highlight movingHighlight = new Highlight(entryInLockedPoint.x,0); 
someChart.highlightValues(new Highlight[] { movingHighlight });
```

And if you want to mark several of graphs then choose from charts datasets.
Hope this was what your were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default implementation to do this in the library.
One way to do this can be to modify the LineChartRenderer class in the library. MpAndroidCharts allows you to draw circles on plotted points, you can modify this by defining a new constructor for LineChartEntry and pass a bitmap to it. You can then draw your bitmap at the plotted point instead of the circle that is drawn.

```
    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    Drawable d;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        LineChartData data = dataList.get(i);
        float val = Float.valueOf(Utils.decimalValuePrecisionTwoPlaces((float) data.getDataVolGallon()));

        if (data.getImageIndex() >= 0) {

            d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), resIcon[data.getImageIndex()]);
            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, false);
            values.add(new Entry(i, val, bitmap));
        } else {

            values.add(new Entry(i, val));
        }

    }
```

Above code is an example for how to set entries with and without bitmap.

```
     if(e.getBitmap() != null)
            {
                c.drawBitmap(e.getBitmap(),mCirclesBuffer[0] - circleRadius, mCirclesBuffer[1] - circleRadius, mRenderPaint);
            }
```

This the code to draw the image from bitmap, just comment the line to draw circles in drawCircles() of LineChartRenderer and use this instead.

Leave a comment if you have any question.Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

To adjust start x,y position of your Marker just override this method in your `MarkerView` class. This also adjust your marker x position if it gets out of bounds of your chart view.

```
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, positionX: Float, positionY: Float) {

    // Check marker position and update offsets.
    var posx = positionX
    val posy: Float
    val w = width
    val h = height

    posx -= if (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels - positionX < w) {
        w.toFloat()
    } else {
        w / 2.toFloat() // Draw marker in the middle of highlight
    }

    posy = lineChart.height - h.toFloat() * 2 // Always starts from middle of chart

    // Translate to the correct position and draw
    canvas.translate(posx, posy)
    draw(canvas)
    canvas.translate(-posx, -posy)
}
```